# What ciphers does Google Cloud Load Balancer support?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup a Load Balancer from the Google Cloud console but I get the following error message:

> Creating SSL certificate "test" failed. Error: The SSL key size is unsupported.

We're using RSA key of length 4096. Is this not supported by Google? Where can I find what ciphers are supported by the google's load balancer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates

Note: This example uses RSA-2048 encryption. Currently, only RSA-2048 and ECDSA P-256 certificates are supported.